# if condition based on a string in for loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I will explain my question in the code itself. Please see the below code

```
var monthNames = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
var ctdate = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;// getting current month
var str=new Date().getFullYear()+'';
str= str.match(/\d{2}$/);//current year is 15(as this year is 2015)
var strprev= str-1;//previous year is 14
var dynmonths = new Array();
dynmonths = monthNames.slice(ctdate).concat(monthNames.slice(0, ctdate));

//here the output comes for last 12 months starting from currentmonth-12 (i.e APR in this case) to current month (i.e MAR)
//dynmonths = ["APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC","JAN","FEB","MAR"];

//I am rotating dynmonths in a for loop to get full dates i.e between (01-APR-14 to 01-MAR-15)

for (var i = 0, length = dynmonths.length; i < length; i++) {
var month = '01-' + dynmonths[i] + '-' + strcurrent;
}
```

But the problem is that `month` is taking `14`for all the months. Which is wrong. After 01-DEC-14 the next month must be 01-JAN-15, 01-FEB-15 and so on. How to check DEC in for loop and after DEC year must change to year+1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code it will work.

```js
function ddd()
{
var monthNames = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
var ctdate = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;// getting current month
var str=new Date().getFullYear()+'';
str= str.match(/\d{2}$/);//current year is 15(as this year is 2015)
var strprev= str-1;//previous year is 14
var dynmonths = new Array();
dynmonths = monthNames.slice(ctdate).concat(monthNames.slice(0, ctdate));

//here the output comes for last 12 months starting from currentmonth-12 (i.e APR in this case) to current month (i.e MAR)
//dynmonths = ["APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC","JAN","FEB","MAR"];

//I am rotating dynmonths in a for loop to get full dates i.e between (01-APR-14 to 01-MAR-15)

for (var i = 0, length = dynmonths.length; i < length; i++) {

if(dynmonths[i]=='JAN')
{
var str = parseInt(str)+parseInt(1);
}
var month = '01-' + dynmonths[i] + '-' + str;
    document.writeln(month);
 document.write("<br />");
   
}
}
```

```html
<body onload="ddd()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variable bool = false and check if you on DEC change it to true (or use counter from more then one year):

```
 var monthNames = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
var ctdate = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;// getting current month
var str=new Date().getFullYear()+'';
str= str.match(/\d{2}$/);//current year is 15(as this year is 2015)
var strprev= str-1;//previous year is 14
var dynmonths = new Array();
dynmonths = monthNames.slice(ctdate).concat(monthNames.slice(0, ctdate));

//here the output comes for last 12 months starting from currentmonth-12 (i.e APR in this case) to current month (i.e MAR)
//dynmonths = ["APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC","JAN","FEB","MAR"];

//I am rotating dynmonths in a for loop to get full dates i.e between (01-APR-14 to 01-MAR-15)

var isPassYear = false;

for (var i = 0, length = dynmonths.length; i < length; i++) {
    var month;
    if (isPassYear)
        //do something
    else
        month  = '01-' + dynmonths[i] + '-' + strcurrent;

    if (monthNames[11] == dynmonths[i]) {
        isPassYear = true;
    }
}
```

second option is to use Date object and append his month by one each time, if you set append to month number 12 it automatic go to the next year.